# Admin/owner of site with Full Control of document library cannot break inheritance of subfolders within that library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, break-inheritance

A user has a document library and wants to create subfolders in that library with customized permissions.

She has the following roles/permissions:

- She is a site collection admin
- She is a member of the site owners group
- She has Full Control of the document library, both via group membership and as an individual (I manually granted her Full Control in case that made a difference, which it did not)
- The subfolders for which she is trying to customize permissions are ones she created herself

Despite this access, she is unable to see the "Stop Inheriting Permissions" button when managing access to the subfolders:

[image: !["Stop Inheriting Permissions" button does not appear]

---

When I try the same thing, the "Stop Inheriting Permissions" button *does* appear for me.  Once I click it, the user is able to customize permissions on the subfolder (because its inheritance has already been broken).  However, this is not an acceptable solution for the end user; she needs to be able to create new folders and customize their permissions in the future, so having me break all the inheritances for her doesn't work.

As far as I'm aware, the only permission level I have and the user doesn't is the global Sharepoint Administrator Azure role across the tenant.  Surely this should not be required to customize permissions on a document library subfolder.

- How can I effectively allow this user to customize permissions on her subfolders?
- If what I've already done should have worked, what troubleshooting steps should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem.

[image]

The reason for this is because your page display ratio is small. Please increase the display ratio of the page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is the reason this is hilarous.  Will reach out to the user and see if zomming in resolves her issue.  Thanks!

Comment: User confirmed that this resolved the issue.  I would never in a million years have figured this out, thanks!

Comment: Hi A_S00. I'm glad I can help you solve the problem. Have a nice day!